# Firebase Node Error: Cannot find module 'axios'

Tags: node.js, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions, http-post

I am attempting to use axios in a scheduled function in my firebase project, I installed it and can see it when I list it along with other dependencies I have been using for a while but when I import it to my project I get the following error:

```
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. 
Error message: Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'axios'
Require stack:
- /workspace/index.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google- 
cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google- 
cloud/functions-framework/build/src/main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/index.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
```

When I run npm list I get this:

```
├── axios@1.6.1
├── firebase-admin@11.9.0
├── node-fetch@3.3.1
└── request@2.88.2
```

I also tried to install and run request and had similar problems but fetch works fine, I also tried adding it manually to my package.json but this also threw errors, I will post my import code below if this helps to understand the issue:

```
const axios = require("axios");

const WEBHOOK_URL = "test";
const text = "Webhook test: ";
axios.post(WEBHOOK_URL, {
  text: text,
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err.toJSON());
d});
```